# Azure function accessible locally only

Tags: azure, azure-functions, fetch, svelte

I have an Azure static web app with a svelte front end and azure server less functions for backend. When developing locally I can connect to the functions perfectly with `fetch(‘https://localhost:7071/api/test’)` But when I replace it with `fetch(‘/api/test’)` it won’t work locally or on the deployed site.

Comment: Not sure about your scenario. but don't you need Root Url for the webapp? fetch(/api/test) is your route. Root Url+Route makes an api url. If its a website still it need the Base Url

Answer (score 0):

Yes! As Lokanath Das said, Root URL + Route makes an API URL.

In The Azure Functions Scenario:
When you run locally, the root URL is combination of `localhost`, `port number` and the `route` (`api/function_name`).

[image]

When you run in the Cloud, then the URL will be: `"https://<azurefunctionappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FunctionName>"` .

We can customize the Azure Function URL Route using HTTP Route Trigger Parameters and can make them optional or we can define the route in the Azure Function Header. Refer [here](https://azurelessons.com/azure-function-http-trigger/) for more information